# Почему разница в скорости умножения и сдвига настолько мала?

Tags: golang

Выполняется простой тест: целочисленное умножение и логический сдвиг в цикле

```
package sample

import "testing"

func TestAdd(t *testing.T) {
}

var x, y [100]int

func BenchmarkMult(b *testing.B) {
    for j := 0; j < len(y); j++ {
        y[j] = j 
    }
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(y); j++ {
            y[j] = x[j] * 345
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkShift(b *testing.B) {
    for j := 0; j < len(y); j++ {
        y[j] = j 
    }
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(y); j++ {
            y[j] = x[j] << 3
        }
    }
}
```

Результат теста:

> PASS
> sample.BenchmarkMult     5000000           556 ns/op
> sample.BenchmarkShift    5000000           449 ns/op

То есть потеря в скорости умножения не больше 24%. В чем причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего причина в неправильном тесте. Видите ли, основное время наверняка теряется на управлении циклом (если конечно Go генерирует оптимальный код). У вас на каждую итерацию выполняется jump.. а может быть, ещё и len вызывается каждый раз, что полностью уничтожает смысл теста.

Comment: Угу, чтобы убрать влияние цикла, надо бы тест предварительно откалибровать. =) Чтоб цикл поиграл сам по себе без умножения. Если, конечно, компилятор его как-то не исказит.

Comment: Всё зависит от того, что такое len. Если len - какая-то функция с зарнее неизвестным побочным результатом, то всё будет ок. А если компилятор уверен, что знает что такое len, то может просто выкинуть цикл.

Comment: UPD: да, len - это builtin, так что он наверняка выкинет ненужный код. Так что выходит, что надо сильно раскручивать циклы, чтобы понять что-нибудь.

Comment: Ну, можно добавить какую-нибудь общую команду, которая точно так же при калибровке бы нивелировалась?=3 Или отключить оптимизацию?

В общем, в любом случае, тест бы переделать надо ^^"

Answer (score 1):

Хм... Современные процы настолько оптимизированы, что на умножение уже отводится не 11 машинных тактов, как раньше, а 4. Это деление остается узким местом - там до 41 такта. И еще, `x[j] * 345` и `x[j] * 8` это разные скорости, вторая команда будет выполнена быстрее, так как в бинарном виде 8 это 00001000b и современный процессор избегает умножения на нулевые биты.

И еще, сами циклы в функциях влияют на замеры скорости. По моим прикидкам, чисто умножение и чисто сдвиг займут порядка 40%-20% от всего времени выполнения функций BenchmarkMult и BenchmarkShift.